# Error on boost phoenix::bind compiling

Tags: c++, boost, boost-phoenix

I'm using phoenix::bind and receiving this error message:

> error C2039: 'bind' : is not a member
>   of 'phoenix'

The code line where I'm using bind and where the error is pointing is:

> phoenix::bind(
>   &OptionalInputPort::eraseDataEditor )
>                   ( phoenix::var( *optionalPort ) )

and I can't figure out what is the problem.

the phoenix include is this line: #include boost/spirit/home/phoenix.hpp

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `phoenix` namespace is *inside* the `boost` namespace (just like everything else in Boost).

```
boost::phoenix::bind( &OptionalInputPort::eraseDataEditor ) ( boost::phoenix::var( *optionalPort ) )
```

To avoid all that typing, you could preface your C++ file with this to create a *namespace alias*:

```
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
```

Then your original code should work. If you're using `bind` a lot, you could tell your compiler that when you say `bind`, you mean the one in `boost::phoenix`:

```
using boost::phoenix::bind;
```

If you're using *lots* of stuff from Phoenix, you could just bring in everything from that namespace, although that can have unintended consequences since it will include the stuff that you didn't even know existed, and that could interfere with your own code.

```
using namespace boost::phoenix;
```